# Format for tokenizing "..." strings

Tags: c

Lets say that I have file which contains the data

```
Data1 "X1 Y1 Z1"
Data2 "X2 Y2 Z2"
Data3 "X3 Y3 Z3"
```

Generally, how would I scan the file and make my program count "X1 Y1 Z1" as a single token?

Comment: You want to read each line in the file into a char array?

Comment: Find the position of the first `"`, the position of the second `"`, and then copy all the characters between them.

Comment: Is your file is having data1 also written in it or only string x1 y1 z1 and so is present?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char data_name[16];
    char data_string[32];

    while(2==fscanf(fp, "%15s \"%31[^\"]\"", data_name, data_string)){
        printf("%s, %s\n", data_name, data_string);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you format it if you wanted both Data1 and "X1 Y1 Z1" to go into a single array?

Comment: @MatthewAllen E.g into `struct data array[MAX_NUMOFREC];`